# Python: Use returned values from a function to another function

Tags: python

With the simple function I am able to get data stored in response variable. With a print statement I can get the data showing correctly.

```
ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2")
def instance_list(instance_name):
    response = ec2_client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'tag:Name',
                'Values': [ instance_name ]
            }
        ]
    )['Reservations']
    return response
    #print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_instance_list = instance_list("example-*")
```

However while trying to import the value of response from the above function to another function, getting error as `NameError: name 'response' is not defined`

```
def my_list():
    list = instance_list(response)
    print(list)
```

Looks like something unidentified.

Comment: You are using a parameter in a function! Response is never defined! You should pass the name of the instance then it returns a response

Comment: You didn't call the returned result `response`, you called it `my_instance_list`, and you did so in a place that deliberately *doesn't* get executed when you `import` the file. Also why would you want to pass that *to* the function that returns it? Your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the basic idea is to use return value of one function to another function

Comment: Also, is multilining the list filters allowed?

Comment: And are *both* functions called `instance_list`?

Comment: Only one function is called instance_list?

Comment: @Wimanicesir yes they are different name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass the varable to the next function, for example

```
my_list(instance_list())
```

Comment: @Rio glad to hear it ;)

Answer (score 0):

*the basic idea is to use return value of one function to another function*

Your function should be this:

```
def my_list():
    # List is equal to the response value of instance list.
    list = instance_list("example-*")

    print(list)
```

## Easy example

```
def add_five_to_number(number):
   number += 5
   return number

def print_number(number):
   higher_number = add_five_to_number(number)   
   print(higher_number)

test_number = 3
print_number(test_number)

# Returns 8
```

Comment: its there under `if __name__ == '__main__'` to pass inputs. However I am trying to fetch output of response from the same function.

Comment: What? :p I don't get what you're trying to say. Fetch output of response from the same function?

Comment: actually the function `instance_list` is taking input from `main` and generating list of dynamic data. Now i am storing those data within response variable. My further goal is to use the data of the variable to another function with any procedure.